# Why is my WinForms Label resized when the Form.Designer code Controls.Add(myLabel) is called?

Tags: winforms, winapi

Why is my WinForms Label resized when the Form.Designer code Controls.Add(myLabel) is called? The label is in side a top panel with a fixed height that never changes (Dock=Top). In the Visual Studio Form Editor, the width of the label is X. In the designer code, the width of the label is still X until the Control.Add() is called on the label. Then the label gets somewhat larger, and the font gets slightly stretched out. Why is that? I really do not want to stretch out the font on the label.

Comment: This happens, when You debug the code step by step and the Controls.Add(myLabel) is executed ?

Comment: Is, Control.Add(myLabel) is executed. Why would it not? It is not possible to step into that function though.

Comment: Do You have set some properties, like autosize = true and some font-regarding stuff  for that label in the properties window ?